# Livedata and many observers and instances

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

It's rather, a question than a problem. I have two entities with a String field called Type. Both have over twenty kinds of type: "Bills", "Transport", "Awards" etc. I want to put all them to the charts, and this is creating little problem because it totally creates over 60((!) 60 because I want to take data by date. For example day, month etc.)instances in ViewModel constructor and over 60 observers in fragment. So my question is:
There is some problem to make it more sexy for code (orderliness), performance of app, or I should not care about it?

One of entity (they are almost same):

```
@Entity(tableName = "expense_table")
public class Expense  {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int expenseId;
private String note;
private Double value;
private String type;
private Long dateLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
private String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy").format(new Date(dateLong));
private static Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
private int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
private int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
private int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
private String weekDay = new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays()[dayOfWeek];
```

Query in Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(value) FROM expense_table WHERE type = :type")
MutableLiveData<List<Double>> getTotalType(String type);
```

One of Repository(As you can see there is many instances now, co code it will more complicated):

```
public class ExpenseRepository {

private ExpenseDao expenseDao;
private LiveData<List<Expense>> allExpensesDay;
private LiveData<List<Expense>> allExpensesMonth;
private LiveData<List<Expense>> allExpenses;
private LiveData<Double> totalValue;
private LiveData<Double> totalValueDay;
private LiveData<Double> totalValueMonth;
private MutableLiveData<List<Double>> totalType;
private String type = "Bills";


public ExpenseRepository(Application application) {
    ExpenseIncomeDatabase database = ExpenseIncomeDatabase.getInstance(application);
    expenseDao = database.expenseDao();
    allExpenses = expenseDao.getAllExpenses();
    allExpensesDay = expenseDao.getExpensesDay();
    allExpensesMonth = expenseDao.getExpensesMonth();
    totalValueDay = expenseDao.getTotalValueDay();
    totalValueMonth = expenseDao.getTotalValueMonth();
    totalValue = expenseDao.getTotalValue();
    totalType = expenseDao.getTotalType(type);
```

One of Repository:

```
private LiveData<Double> totalExpenseValue;
private LiveData<Double> totalIncomeValue;
private MutableLiveData<List<Double>> totalType;


public TotalStatsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    ExpenseRepository expenseRepository = new ExpenseRepository(application);
    ExpenseRepository expenseChartsRepository = new ExpenseRepository(application);
    IncomeRepository incomeRepository = new IncomeRepository(application);
    totalExpenseValue = expenseChartsRepository.getTotalValue();
    totalIncomeValue = incomeRepository.getTotalValue();
    totalType = expenseRepository.getTotalType();
}

public LiveData<Double> getTotalExpenseValue() {
    return totalExpenseValue;
}

public LiveData<Double> getTotalIncomeValue() {
    return totalIncomeValue;
}

public LiveData<List<Double>> getTotalType() {
    return totalType;
}
```

As you can see there is a lot of code now. In future it will be much more. Maybe it stupid question, but I just care about orderliness and performance.

Comment: You can try with `MediatorLiveData` or `Transformation` also.

Comment: I know about them, but I can use in them more than just two livedatas?